# How to add properties (markers, geopoints, etc...) to a Google Android Map v2 created programmatically

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

The code used is this:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;

MapFragment mMapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.rl_map, mMapFragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();

mMap = mMapFragment.getMap();
```

and it shows the map  inside the relative layout (R.id.rl_map), but when I try to put the marker with:

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Hello world"));
```

it gives Null pointer exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the `GoogleMap` does not yet exist. `commit()` schedules the map to be created, but it is not created by the time you try calling `getMap()`.

Either:

- Switch to inflating a layout containing the `MapFragment`, as you can call `getMap()` after inflation is complete, or
- Delay the `getMap()` call to some later point, or
- Subclass `MapFragment` and call `getMap()` and add your marker in a method like `onActivityCreated()` (basically, anything called after `onCreateView()` has completed)

Answer (score 0):

you should:

```
 Googlemap map =((SupportMapFragment)       getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
```

and

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Hello world"));
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesnt work because the fragment is created by code, it is not in the layout. Anyway, if the fragment is in the layout, you method works